# reading data from CSV and show continuous graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I am trying to plot a chart which will read a data from csv file which is appending on every minute with latest data as per below format.

The chart will continue reading data from csv file and show the graph on every second wise. Can you please help me on this? I want to show the exact time which are coming from file should be show on graph.

CSV format..

```
time,count
18:01:00,3
18:01:01,4
....
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var csv = [],
      x;

  Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
      useUTC: false
    }
  });

  var data = 'time,count\n18:01:00,3\n18:01:01,4';

  //$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
  var lines = data.split('\n');

  $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    if(lineNo > 0) {
      var items = line.split(',');
      useUTC: false;
      x = items[0].split(':');
      csv.push([Date.UTC(2015,1,1,x[0],x[1],x[2]), parseFloat(items[1])]);
    }
  });

  console.log(csv);

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'spline',
      animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
      marginRight: 10,
      useUTC: false,
      events: {
        load: function () {

          // set up the updating of the chart each second
          var series = this.series[0];

          setInterval(function () {
            var l = series.data.length - 1,
                lastX = series.data[l].x;

            $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
              var lines = data.split('\n'),
                  len = lines.length,
                  items = lines[len - 1].split(','),
                  x = items[0].split(':'),
                  y = parseFloat(items[1]);
              useUTC: false;
              x = Date.UTC(2015,1,1,x[0],x[1],x[2]);

              if(x !== lastX) {
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
              }
            });
          }, 1000); //refresh each 1 second
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'TPS Data'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Value'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 3,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
          Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
          Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },


    series: [{
      name: 'Count',
      data: csv
    }]
  });

  //});
});
```

```css
div {
  min-width: 50px;  
  height: 200px; 
  margin: 0 auto;  
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style=""></div>
```

**Note** In the snippet I was replace the ajax function `$.get` with hardcoded data so it will show the result but the question is about the `ajax` way.

Comment: Ok, where is the question? Your code doesn't work because you have `useUTC: false;` which produces an error (inside this function: `$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line)  { ... }`).

Comment: Hi If i removed that also not showing the graph properly

Comment: It works for me, see: http://jsfiddle.net/sz0esszz/4/ - note that I change `useUTC` to `true`.